# how to find all usages of jQuery or Zepto in your code

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, zepto

My team and I want to maintain a low cost for switching from Zepto to another framework or native browser calls (we only target WebKit) while using it.

What are the tactics of keeping track of the places in the code where Zepto is used?
Is there anything better that maintaining a Readme list of methods used?
How would you do it?

Comment: Correction: How would you go about replacing Zepto with native browser calls. How to find all methods like 'parents()' being used in the code?

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**: You can use `noConflict` to assign some nice, unique name to the `jQuery` function (perhaps `jQuery` itself as that's built-in, but if that's a pain something else readily distinguished from other things, like `$jq` or some such — `noConflict` returns the `jQuery` function so you can do that, e.g. `var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();`).

**Zepto**: Despite claiming a "jQuery-compatible syntax," it doesn't appear to support `noConflict` per se. However, it looks like if `$` is already defined on the `window` object, it will leave it alone, because of this line:

```
'$' in window || (window.$ = Zepto);
```

So define `$` before loading `Zepto` and then only use `Zepto` in your code (or assign something to it that's equally unique, like `$jq` or `$zt`, etc. — e.g., `var $zt = Zepto;`).

In either case: Then search your code for those if/when you need to find those bits.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a little bit with keeping namespaces separate, but doesn't help estimating what it would be like to replace Zepto with native browser calls. Ie this tactic doesn't help find uses of methods like 'parents()' from Zepto.

Comment: @ulver: Not sure I'm following. You'll see the `$zt()` call that gives you the Zepto wrapper for the elements you match, and then you'll see the `parents()` call. E.g. in an event handler, "`var x = $zt(this); x.parents().css("color", "blue");`" or whatever. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond searching for $ and specific methods, you could identify which methods are in use by logging their usage in running code.

The following code will log the function used and the stack trace every time you make a jQuery call but not log any internal calls made by jQuery.

```
<script>
(function(){
var insideJQuery = false;
function replaceMethod(obj, method, prefix) {
    var oldMethod = obj[method];
    if(typeof oldMethod !== "function")
        return;

    obj[method] = function() {
        var externalCall = !insideJQuery;
        insideJQuery = true;
        var output = oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);

        if(externalCall) {
            console.log(prefix + method + ' called');
            console.trace();
            insideJQuery = false;
        }

        return output;
    }
}

for(var method in $.fn) {
    if(method != 'constructor' &&
       method != 'init')
        replaceMethod($.fn, method, '$.fn.');
}

for(var method in $) {
    if(method != 'Event')
        replaceMethod($, method, '$.');
}
})();
</script>
```

The exception of course would be jQuery calls inside jQuery calls like `$(document).ready(function(){$('div')});`.

Answer (score -4):

Um, you could search for the `$` sign?

Every method like `parents()` will be called on something that was ultimately created with the `$` sign. So if you find all instances of `$` and trace the use of the resulting variables you'll have everything.